# Amazon EventBridge won't send events via 2 rules nor 2 targets within one rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, amazon-transcribe

Within Amazon Eventbridge, I'm listening for Transcribe events such as the following:

```
{
"source": ["aws.transcribe"],
  "detail-type": ["Transcribe Job State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "TranscriptionJobStatus": ["FAILED", "COMPLETED"]
  }
}
```

I need to send this event to development (via Ngrok), to staging, and to production, each time with a query parameter indicating which environment triggered the transcription.

Having worked on this simple usecase for a full day, it simple seems bugged:
The first rule, target and connection that I set up functions fine.

- Adding additional targets to this rule do not function
- Brand new rules I add to receive and handle the events do not work
- Deleting everything and rebuilding, again, the first rule, target and connection will function (even if this is to a different environment.)

So for example, I've had dev but not staging working, ripped it all down, and then rebuilt, and ended up with staging but not dev working.

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it after considerable trial and error.

It's not clear what the root cause is. Likely issues were:

- When a role is created for your connections the first time, it will be created with the correct permissions. Check all IAM permissions with a fine tooth comb.
- AWS Events only fire when the triggering system and the rules are in the same region (e.g. us-east-1)

To help debug, export the cloud formation templates for systems that are working and are not working to see if there are any differences in the set-up.

---

The rest of this answer is simply going to be advice to anyone considering using AWS EventBridge: **run**.